# Using Google analytics IDFA, Which Advertising Identifier option to choose at the time of submission to App Store?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, app-store-connect, itunes-store, idfa

I am developing app in which i have added Google analytics. I have enabled **IDFA** to get information related to user's gender/age.

At the time of App submission there are options to select -

Does this app use the Advertising Identifier(IDFA)?

But options for that:

1. Serve advertising within the app
2. Attribute this app installation to a previously serve advertisement
3. Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served advertisement

I am not sure where my app belongs to.
I am **not serving any ads in my app**. I have added this just to get user's gender/age information.

Can anyone please give me advice on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Apple support Team -

> Section 3.3.12 of the Program License Agreement states that usage of the Advertising Identifier is limited only for advertising purposes.
>
> "You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have contracted to serve advertising) may use the Advertising Identifier, and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising Identifier, **only for the purpose of serving advertising.**"

In Short, I can not enable IDFA to collect user's information.